# OSGi User Admin Service User Objects

Tags: java, security, osgi, user-permissions, user-roles

I wanted to use the OSGi User Admin service for security but I could not get enough resource about it. 
I want to authenticate certain bundles that will be installed in the system and represent them by User-Objects after authentication. So that I can later use these User-Object for authorization.

I have 2 questions:

1. Since I have more than one user, how can I know which bundle is calling a secured method? (I don't want to pass the user object as a parameter to every method I want to control).
2. How can I relate the bundles with the User-Object representing them?

I want to have one bundle as an entry point that will authenticate all these other bundles and have control over them. But I couldn't even find anyone mentioning using User Admin service. Is there another  option for OSGi security besides CPA? I would like to use this to secure my console as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a few questions rolled into one. Let me try to answer them all.

First of all, the UserAdmin service is specified in the OSGi compendium. There, it explains how users, roles, etc are defined and how you can use the service to answer questions like "does this user have role X"? What that does not tell you is how to use this service as part of a security solution. That's up to you.

Regarding question 1, which is not an OSGi related problem (but rather a generic one in Java applications), there traditionally have been a few methods of passing on a "context" to a method:

1. Making it an argument to each method (which you do not want to do).
2. Storing it in the ThreadLocal context (which is fairly popular in JavaEE, but has its downsides if your application delegates work to threadpools that might or might not pass on such a context correctly).
3. If this is all about security for services that you implement yourself (and not third-party ones) you could use the ServiceFactory pattern in OSGi to give each client bundle it's own context (and embed the User object in there; for examples look at the LogService implementation in Felix, which uses that mechanism to add a bundle.id to each log message).
4. Sometimes it also makes sense to embed the context not in an extra parameter to your methods, but as part of some existing object (so effectively you are then associating the context with specific objects, which might or might not make sense depending on your domain).
5. Another option would be to use the Apache Felix Dependency Manager to intercept the services you want to secure (with an aspect) and, in the aspect, figure out what bundle is calling, and do the proper security checks (probably requires a more detailed answer if you want to give that a go).

Regarding question 2, bundles have a symbolic name that identifies them. You could use that to associate a bundle with a User. There are other options, but this is the most obvious one.

Regarding your question about options for OSGi security, I would say ConditionalPermissionAdmin (and the older PermissionAdmin) is the only solution to address security within the OSGi framework itself, if you want to specify what specific bundles can and cannot do in terms of importing packages, using services, accessing the filesystem, etc. You would have to write your own custom permissions if you want to integrate this with UserAdmin.

Finally, the secure console is yet another thing you need to address yourself. You might be able to find some building blocks as I know there have been people implementing some role based access (David Bosschaert comes to mind). However, the console is a complex and powerful thing, so answering this question alone takes more than a simple SO question because it depends what and how fine grained you want to implement this.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the detailed answer. I am using declarative services to be relieved from dealing with different service registration issues so I think Options 3 & 5 won't work for me. I already have Conditional Permission Admin implemented for security. I wanted to use User Admin to have a role based control over services to be later added by third party. Option 1 & your answer for Question 2 are the feasible options that I see for me now. But since User Admin doesn't give a complete control over the entire process I am thinking to get rid of it completely.

Comment: On a German book "Die OSGi Service Platform" [link](http://www.amazon.de/Service-Platform-Eine-Einf%C3%BChrung-Eclipse-Equinox/dp/389864457X) they have covered User Admin service and give an example to secure a console but it is a very simplified version where only one user is assumed to exist & doesn't mention the above issues with multiple users at all. Do u know any other complete reference that uses User Admin for role based security? It would have been nice if there was a standardized approach for the whole process.